# Creating a global object in PHP

Tags: php, com

I need to create a global object that can be reachable from my script's other php files.

My point is, create **only one** COM object when script / server started. And this COM object will wait for my commands to to some processing work.

I've tried to write a class to make it happen but, when i refresh page, my class reloads and my static variables are re-defining.

Is there any code or any class or way to solve this problem?

Thank you all.

Comment: PHP doesn't maintain state between page requests (such as a page refresh) unless you maintain it in $_SESSION; and I don't believe that a COM object can be maintained in session. A possible alternative might be to create a daemon process, always running on the server that maintains your COM object, and then make requests from your PHP script to the daemon process

Comment: Nope, that's not what i actually want. My point is, I'll create a COM object (DLL connection) in a differend php file. This file'll wait my commands to make some process. For example, COM.php file is running and waiting my command. test.php is my php file to send commands to COM object that i've created in COM.php file.

Comment: You may use APC or memcache to store objects in memory. http://php.net/apc_store

Comment: @jgb - note that objects stored in APC or memcache are __serialized__ in the same way as objects stored in $_SESSION; and it isn't possible to serialize a reference to a resource

Comment: thanks. I understand that. So, how can I manage that COM object (DLL) connection the way that i mean ? I've to open that connection once and send it requests and receive the returned values like string, object, int etc. (Sorry about my English by the way)

Comment: @Mark the advantage over $_SESSION is that the object is not bound to an single session. Ressources could be handled by __sleep and __wakeup.

Comment: That's an advantage; but I'd still be concerned that having to disconnect and re-establish the COM connection (via __sleep and __wakeup) negates what OP is wanting to do; because my understanding of the question is that they want a persistent COM session... as far as I'm aware, a daemon process is the only way to maintain a persistent COM connection

Comment: Hi again, I've solved my problem with permanent TCP / IP connection. Created a background PHP file which works 24/7. This background file waits my requests via TCP / IP connection and queries the COM connection :)

Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you're outside of a function, you can define it. Once you are in a function, you use the `global` keyword to "pull it into" the function.

Example:

```
<?php
$foo = "bar";
echo $foo; // bar

function test1() {
  echo $foo; // error
}
test1();

function test2() {
  global $foo;
  echo $foo; // bar
}
test2();
?>
```

Comment: That's not what the OP's asking for. He wants an object that persists across multiple script invocations.